# How create text composing with rectangle? (canvas, pixi.js, three.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, pixi.js

My task is to make a dynamic progress bar.
Firstly, the time that remains until a certain date should change. There are no problems with this. The main question is how to make the numbers fill in the contour? (this circuit is also considered dynamically from the remaining one)
Interested in a solution on a blank canvas or three.js or pixi.js [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvfKr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily possible using svg and a tiny bit of javascript.
The trick is to use a linear-gradient (that is actually just a single sharp step) to fill the text.

Working example:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const gradientStops = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll("#fillGradient stop")
);

input.addEventListener("input", ev => {
  // value is a number between 0 and 1
  const value = ev.target.valueAsNumber;
  gradientStops.forEach(stop => {
    stop.offset.baseVal = value;
  });
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; background: red; font-family: sans-serif;  }
svg { width: 100%; height: auto; color: white; }
svg text {
  font-size: 60px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  stroke: currentColor; 
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: url(#fillGradient)
}
input { position: fixed; bottom: 1em; display: block; width: 90%; margin: 0 5%; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="fillGradient">
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="currentColor" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="transparent" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <text x="0" y="60">10D:20:42:12</text>
</svg>

<input type="range" min=0 max=1 step=0.001 />
```

If you need to do this based on canvas, I think the easiest way would be like

- render the text with white stroke and fill
- use `clearRect` to remove the part of the text
- render the text again, this time with transparent fill-color